# How to quickly switch to / locate a worksheet in many worksheets with long names in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I found myself often have to switching between different worksheets in the same workbook, especially when there are more than 5 worksheet in the same file with long names, its really tedious work to simply locating the correct worksheet. One always have to keep scrolling the tabs.

Is there any way to easily switch between many worksheets in the same workbook?

Comment: You can use `Ctrl` + `Pgup/PgDn` to cycle through sheets, but I don't know of anyway to switch directly to a sheet you can't currently see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following screenshots are from Excel 2016, but it'll work under Excel 2010 as well. If you right click on the left/right arrows by the Sheets, it'll show you a list of all your Sheets.

[image: Excel 2016]

[image]

Comment: Actually I just bumped into this menu today, Hence this question (see if there's any approach even better). Never realized its existence.but it really makes life easier, Never understand why those tabs still go horizontal in the wide screen days. Really awkward to keep scrolling all the time!

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to comment as I don't have enough reputation.

you may want to have a look on [this](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=120)
(it creates a 'table of conten't worksheet in your workbook)

best: to try on this, first insert empty row to every worksheet in this workbook